# If something is broken on the ground, it lies in _____?

Tags: synonyms

I cannot remember the synonym for lying broken on the ground. I remember that it starts with "lies in "...

For example, if a plate is shattered on the ground, it lies in **_**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lies in pieces? Most of the phrases given by dg99 seem to operate at a higher level of abstraction.

I can't find a canonical books/wiktionary quote but there are a reasonable number of examples in Google.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google books:

If a plate is shattered on the ground,

- it lies in smithereens (2 results) <sup>[1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20lies%20in%20smithereens%22&num=30&client=firefox-a&hs=Pgl&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=YS9YU5DUDsfNygO58IIw&ved=0CA4Q_AUoAQ&biw=1339&bih=588)</sup>
- ... in bits (19 results) <sup>[2](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&biw=1339&bih=588&tbm=bks&q=%22it%20lies%20in%20bits%22&oq=%22it%20lies%20in%20bits%22&gs_l=serp.12...37901.41694.0.43473.15.15.0.0.0.0.152.1718.4j11.15.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..13.2.283.uxlCixuDkgE)</sup>
- ... in tatters (59 results) <sup>[3](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&biw=1339&bih=588&tbm=bks&q=%22it%20lies%20in%20tatters%22&oq=%22it%20lies%20in%20tatters%22&gs_l=serp.12...58189.61072.0.63037.9.9.0.0.0.0.176.1100.4j5.9.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..8.1.137.c3D__1gPEYA)</sup>
- ... in pieces (196 results) <sup>[4](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&biw=1339&bih=588&tbm=bks&q=%22it%20lies%20in%20pieces%22&oq=%22it%20lies%20in%20pieces%22&gs_l=serp.12...40196.44440.0.46345.11.11.0.0.0.0.218.1485.3j7j1.11.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..9.2.349.V_E9Vqmc4YA)</sup>
- ... in **[fragments](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fragment)** (467 results) <sup>[5](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&biw=1339&bih=588&tbm=bks&q=%22it%20lies%20in%20fragments%22&oq=%22it%20lies%20in%20fragments%22&gs_l=serp.3...74696.79932.0.81051.15.15.0.0.0.0.172.1783.6j9.15.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..14.1.169.bfY2_efNbzM)</sup>
- it lies shattered (476 results) <sup>[6](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=rcs&biw=1339&bih=588&tbm=bks&q=%22it%20lies%20shattered%22&oq=%22it%20lies%20shattered%22&gs_l=serp.12...8674.13175.0.15310.6.6.0.0.0.0.226.931.0j5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.42.serp..3.3.528.XXDg6BFFGW8)</sup>

Comment: tatters implies a material that can be torn, such as cloth.

Comment: I doubt you can find tattered plates or smashed and broken cloth.

Comment: @Oldcat "plate" was only an example suggested by the OP, but my main point is that fragments, expresses the concept of something broken better than *pieces* IMO.

Comment: No shards? My plates always end in shards.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I had checked on Google books, surprisingly the expression "it lies in shards", if I recall correctly, had only one example!

Answer (score 1):

How about ...

- ruins
- shambles
- tatters